# Почему reflect и unsafe выводит разные значения у одного объекта в Golang?

Tags: golang, рефлексия

Есть такой код

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    s := "hello, world!"
    hello := s[:5]
    world := s[7:]
    fmt.Printf("s = `%s`, sh = %v, sp = %d\n",
        s,
        *(*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)),
        reflect.ValueOf(&s).Pointer(),
    )

    fmt.Printf("hello = `%s`, helloh = %v, hellop = %d\n",
        hello,
        *(*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&hello)),
        reflect.ValueOf(&hello).Pointer(),
    )

    fmt.Printf("world = `%s`, worldh = %v, worldp = %d\n",
        world,
        *(*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&world)),
        reflect.ValueOf(&world).Pointer(),
    )

    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    s1 := slice[:5]
    s2 := slice[4:]
    fmt.Printf("slice = `%v`, sh = %v, sp = %d\n",
        slice,
        *(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&slice)),
        reflect.ValueOf(slice).Pointer(),
    )

    fmt.Printf("s1 = `%v`, s1h = %v, s1p = %d\n",
        s1,
        *(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s1)),
        reflect.ValueOf(s1).Pointer(),
    )

    fmt.Printf("s2 = `%v`, s2h = %v, s2p = %d\n",
        s2,
        *(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s2)),
        reflect.ValueOf(s2).Pointer(),
    )
}
```

вывод

```
s = `hello, world!`, sh = {4817792 13}, sp = 824633786960
hello = `hello`, helloh = {4817792 5}, hellop = 824633786976
world = `world!`, worldh = {4817799 6}, worldp = 824633786992

slice = `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`, sh = {824633860176 10 10}, sp = 824633860176
s1 = `[1 2 3 4 5]`, s1h = {824633860176 5 10}, s1p = 824633860176
s2 = `[5 6 7 8 9 10]`, s2h = {824633860208 6 6}, s2p = 824633860208
```

В случае со строкой, почему выводится другой **sh** от **Pointer()** 4817792 и 824633786960 например, в то время как в слайсах они одинаковые. И почему у **s** и **hello** одинаковые **sh** - 4817792, а у **world** отличается, но по сути это же срез исходной строки?

Тот же вопрос и про слайсы. И вообще, что конкретно значат эти числа, это какой-то адрес где хранятся сущности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reflect.StringHeader`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#StringHeader)

```
type StringHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
}
```

Строки `s` и `s[:5]` начинаются в памяти в одном и том же месте, поэтому у них одинаковое значение указателя `Data`. Переменная `world` равна `s[7:]`, то есть у этой строки указатель данных сдвинут на 7 байтов относительно строки `s`. Именно это показывает вывод вашей программы: данные строки `s` начинается с адреса `4817792`, а строки `s[7:]` с 4817799.

Тип [`SliceHeader`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#SliceHeader) устроен аналогично:

```
type SliceHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
    Cap  int
}
```

Указатель на данные, текущая длина, максимальная возможная длина (можно делать `append` без реаллокации до тех пор, пока `Len <= Cap`)

Данные для `slice[:5]` и `slice` начинаются с одного и того же адреса. Поэтому у них одинаковые значения `Data` и `Cap`. Кстати, это означает, что если вы сделаете `append(s1, 123)`, то значение `slice` тоже изменится, ведь у них общий буфер.

Данные для `slice[4:]` начинаются на четыре `int`-а дальше, что на 64-х битной машине равно `4*8=32` байта: `824633860176  + 32 = 824633860208`

Буфер у `slice` и `slice[4:]` общий, поэтому максимальная длина `slice[4:]` на четыре `int`-а меньше: `slice[4:].Cap == slice.Cap - 4`.

Как-то так.

Кстати, у вас `Value.Pointer` используется по-разному. В случае `reflect.ValueOf(&s).Pointer()` вы получаете указатель на `s`, а не на данные `s`. В случае `reflect.ValueOf(slice).Pointer()` вы получаете указатель именно на данные среза.

**UPDATE**

Про указатель на объект и указатель на данные.

В Go объект типа `string` и массив байтов, которые этой строкой являются, лежат в разных местах. Аналогично с массивами - переменная типа массив ссылается на `SliceHeader`, а конкретные байты лежат совсем в другом месте.

Указатель на объект `string` - это `unsafe.Pointer(&s)`. Физически по этому указателю лежит структура `StringHeader`. Данные лежат по адресу `StringHeader.Data`. Ваш пример это отлично показывает - объект лежит по адресу `sp = 824633786960`, а данные по адресу `sh.Data = 4817792`.

Теперь о том, что получилось в случае с массивами. В интерфейсе `reflect.Value` есть метод `Pointer`. Этот метод очень особенный: он работает для функций, указателей и массивов/срезов. Для остальных типов он паникует. Попробуйте `reflect.ValueOf(s).Pointer()`, убедитесь сами.

Для массивов этот метод возвращает **указатель на данные**, а не указатель на объек. Другими словами, этот метод возвращает `SliceHeader.Data` способом, который не зависит от реализации массивов в рантайме Go. Возможно, в будущем они что-нибудь поменяют, или вовсе отменят `SliceHeader`, а `Pointer()` будет по-прежнему работать. Итак, для массивов "канонный" способ получить указатель на данные - `reflect.ValueOf(slice).Pointer()`

Обратите внимание, что для массивов вы применяли метод `Pointer` непосредственно к объекту типа `[]int`. Поэтому он вам давал указатель на данные. В случае строк вы применяли метод `Pointer` к объекту типа `*string`. Для указателей метод `Pointer` возвращает сам указатель.

Для строк нет стандартного способа получить указатель на данные, есть только костыль `((*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&obj)).Data`.

Comment: Спасибо теперь вроде всё ясно! Но еще один вопрос, для того чтобы узнать где лежит объект в памяти, как(с помощью чего) это правильно сделать? Код со строками выдал разные данные ```sh = {4817792 13}, sp = 824633786960```, а у слайса одинаковые ```sh = {824633860176 10 10}, sp = 824633860176```. То есть в строках разные 4817792 и 824633786960, но у слайсов одинаковые 824633860176 и 824633860176, исходя из этого не могу понять как получить адрес где лежат данные через ```*(*reflect.StringHeader(<Obj>))(unsafe.Pointer(&obj))``` или ```reflect.ValueOf(&obj).Pointer()```

Comment: @Владислав я добавил ответ про указатель на данные.